# Drop down List Filter with ASPX , AJAX controls,or JQuery?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, jquery-selectors

I am looking for a filtering mechanism, as the user types in the drop down box I want to filter the list to the list items that match what the user is typing. Is there any premade control for this or does anyone know the best way to achieve this feature?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ajax Control Toolkit has an auto complete extender (http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_AutoComplete.ashx).

JQuery has an auto complete feature in the UI core (http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/).

Others built into third party tools.

HTH.

Comment: The JQuery for combobox is exactly what I was looking for, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well, that's the simple solution. The Ajax Control Toolkit AutoComplete Extender comes in handy if you wish to accomplish this. You may also have to implement a small Service.

Check it out and you will tell us.